# What's the correct C++ syntax to use typedef'ed inner class in member function definitions?

Tags: c++, typedef, inner-classes

What's the correct syntax to use a typedef of an inner class when defining member functions? As you can see from the code below, I'm trying to use the typedef of an inner class in its ctor definition, but I can't quite find the right syntax - can someone please help?

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer
{
public:
  Outer( int a );

  class ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong
  {
  public:
    ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong( int a );
  private:
    int a_;
  };

  typedef ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong Inner;

private:
  Inner inner_;
};

Outer::Outer( int a )
  : inner_( a )
{
}

//Outer::Inner::Inner( int a ) // This doesn't compile
//Outer::Inner::Outer::Inner( int a ) // This looks like nonsense, but I tried it anyway. It does not compile, obviously.
Outer::ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong::ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong( int a ) // This compiles.
  : a_( a )
{
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Outer::Inner inner( 2 ); // Although this looks "similar to" line 27, it compiles.
  std::cout << "hello, world." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'd also like to ask why the use of `Outer::Inner` in `main()`, while similar to the compile-breaking line 27, compiles, while the latter is bad.

Comment: You can do `Outer::Inner::ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong( int a )`

Comment: Thank you - any insight on why the sort of halfway-looking syntax? I'm always curious about syntactic oddities.

Comment: The "constructor name" has to be the actual class name

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but the second `ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong` isn't a type-name. It's the name of the constructor of the class. I'm pretty sure that's why it has to be written that way.

Comment: @M.M - Any insight on why that is so, or is it "just the way the language is written"? Thank you, though; you and Justin have answered my question (points for answering if anyone likes)

Comment: @StoneThrow Not entirely sure but I can imagine it getting confusing in cases like template specializations that use different typedef names.   Consider using `Inner` as the class name in the first place

Comment: `Outer::ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong` is still the effective class name, "Inner" is an alias created by `typedef` (or in newer syntax, `using` is prefereable). You can use Inner when referring that class, but to define it, you should define what typedef was referring to - that is  the `Outer::ThisInnerClassNameIsAwfullyLong class`